# Why do I have to refresh the page in order to connect to the peer system?

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, videochat

I am trying to create an app that allow users to create a videochat event room (by inserting it into the backend's database) and then let other users that have an account on the website to join it. At the moment, the login part is not created, but it is not a problem.

The backend is done in Spring Boot RestAPI (and runs on 8080) and the frontend in nodejs (and runs on 3000). The Peer To Peer system is done using an nodejs server and Peer.js API (and runs on 3001).

The main question is the following:

When the user clicks on an event fetched from the DB, if it is the first one, it becomes host. If not, then it becomes a simple user. When a user enters the room, the host have to refresh the page(like to reconnect to the room) and so does the user, in order to be both connected. Why is so? I will give you the files codes bellow.

The second one: Why this system is not working for Safari and, if it works how to solve it?

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var http = require("http")
    // BELOW IT IS THE BACKEND CONNECTION. TO TEST YOUR CODE, YOU NEED AN ARRAY THAT HAVE ARRAYS WITH sessionID AND name PARAMS LIKE SO: [{"sessionID":"1231", "name":"event"},{...}].
    http.get("http://localhost:8080/events", (resp) => {
        let data = "";
        resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on("end", () => {
            console.log(data);
            res.render('index', {events: data})
        });
    })
    .on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
})

app.get('/join', (req, res) => {
    res.render('join')
})

app.get('/event', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        console.log("User connected: " + userId)
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
        })
  })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

script.js:

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, { // user id
  host: '/', // path to event
  port: '3001' // post
})
const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true
const peers = {}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
}).then(stream => {
  addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

  myPeer.on('call', call => {
    call.answer(stream) // HOST SEE OTHERS
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => { // OTHERS SEE HOST
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
  })

  socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    console.log(peers);
  })
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})

myPeer.on('open', id => {
  socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

room.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template</title>
    <script>
        const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <style>
        #video-grid{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
            grid-auto-rows: 300px;
        }
        video{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>
    <script>
        var raw = "<%= events %>"
        raw = raw.replaceAll("&#34;", "\"") // DONE BECAUSE WHEN PASSING THE PARAM, INSTEAD OF " IT IS THE &#34; ENTITY
        var events = JSON.parse(raw)
        
        window.onload = (event) => {
            var table = document.querySelectorAll("#events")[0];
            table.innerHTML = '';
            for (let index = 0; index < events.length; index++) {
                table.innerHTML += "<tr><td><a href='/" + events[index].sessionID + "'>" + events[index].name + "</a></td></tr>"
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="/event">Create Event</a></h1>
    <table id="events">

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```